# How to check disk space for Nagios

Tags: nagios

How to check disk space manually in the Host management screen in nagios.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [check_disk_space](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-and-Systems-Management/check_disk_space/details) plugin for that.